# How to find discontinuity of piece wise function?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, proof-explanation

It was a question i encountered on an entrance exam question paper
Let  $$ f(x)=\begin{cases}
2x,\text{if x is irrational}\\[2pt]
x+3,\text{if x is rational}\\
\end{cases}$$
Find the points of discontinuity.

I am trying to solve it but I can't find any logic. Can someone explain it in simple terms.i prefer sequential method.

Comment: Generally, when a piecewise function is $g(x)$ when $x$ is rational and $h(x)$ when $x$ is irrational, the continuity points are the points where $g(x) = h(x)$. Here  $x = 3$ is the only point of continuity.

Comment: Thank you for explaining in simpler terms

Comment: I can post an answer if you need further explanation. Let me know.

Comment: No i understood.. thank you..

Comment: @User8128: I think your comment could/should be posted as an answer. It explains succinctly and exactly to the point.

Comment: @Just_to_Answer good note. I will post it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, when a piecewise function $f(x)$ is defined as $g(x)$ when $x$ is rational and $h(x)$ when $x$ is irrational (where $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are continuous), the function $f(x)$ is continuous iff $g(x) = h(x)$. Here, the only continuity point is $x=3$ since $2x = x+3$ iff $x = 3$.